# If $a,b,c\ge0:a+b+c=3,$ prove $\sqrt{a+b+b^2}+\sqrt{b+c+c^2}+\sqrt{c+a+a^2}\ge 3\sqrt{3}.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, buffalo-way

> **Problem.** Let $a,b,c\ge0:a+b+c=3.$ Prove that $$\sqrt{a+b+b^2}+\sqrt{b+c+c^2}+\sqrt{c+a+a^2}\ge 3\sqrt{3}.$$
> Equality holds at $(1,1,1);(0,0,3).$

I tried to use some classical inequality but it seems hard to apply. The following is just a thought:

By AM-GM$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a+b+b^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{3(a+b+b^2)}\ge 2\sqrt{3}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+b+b^2}{a+b+b^2+3},$$which is not good enough.

I think we can find suitable yields $a+b+b^2=f(a,b,c)$ and save two of equality cases.

Hope to see some ideas. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: You could reformulate this into a quartic polynomial inequality (in terms of $a,b,c$) by using that WLOG $a\geq 1 \geq c$ and taking squares two times? To deal with the polynomial, you could use Hilbert's theorem.

Comment: @above, what is Hilbert's theorem ?

Comment: Non-negative polynomial is a sum of squares.

Comment: Could you please post your solution?

Comment: I don't have a solution, I'm just providing a blueprint to a potential solution. There's a slight chance my blueprint fails when the second square has to be taken. In any case, this way could be overcomplicated.

Comment: Oh, I miscounted: you have to take squares three times and the resulting polynomial inequality would be 8th degree :/

Comment: It might be something easier. I will try more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*My third proof (Sketch)*.

**Fact 1**: Let $x, y, z \ge 0$ such that
$$3(x^2y^2 + y^2z^2 + z^2x^2) + x^2y^2z^2(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \ge 12, $$
and
$$(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)(3 + 2x^2y^2z^2) \ge 15.$$
Then, $x + y + z \ge 3$.

$\phantom{2}$

Let
$$x = \sqrt{(a + b + b^2)/3}, \quad y = \sqrt{(b + c + c^2)/3}, \quad z = \sqrt{(c + a + a^2)/3}.$$
We can prove that
$$3(x^2y^2 + y^2z^2 + z^2x^2) + x^2y^2z^2(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \ge 12$$
and
$$(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)(3 + 2x^2y^2z^2) \ge 15.$$

By Fact 1, we have $x + y + z \ge 3$.

We are done.

Comment: Could you please share us how did you find fact 1?

Comment: @TATAbox The way I did was kind of try and error.

Comment: I know you meant. It is just a miracle of inequalities!

Comment: @TATAbox There are many things to discover in this way. How to construct simple expressions which imply $x + y + z \ge 3$.

Comment: Yes, as I posted a topic about CY3. Some relatives between the yields might lead to desired result. It is likely way to research inequality rather than use it in a competition.

Comment: @TATAbox Here is an [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456300/prove-that-sum-limits-mathrmcyc-left-a-frac1b-1-right-left-b) of finding the expression which implies the desired inequality.

Comment: I accepted your answer. I'll post the proof of fact soon. Could you please check my lastest answer?

Comment: @TATAbox Did you check $a = 3, b = 0, c= 0$?

Comment: Oh, thank you. It is not true, hmm.

Comment: @TATAbox Waiting for your proof.

Comment: I found a big mistake in my proof, hmm. Do you have a simple idea to prove fact 1?

Comment: @TATAbox I did not consider its proof. I think pqr may work. I found that additional condition is $q^2 \ge 3pr$ (the other conditions are given in Fact 1) all of which imply $p \ge 3$. Perhaps this help.

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{4a^2+c^2+ab+2ac+bc}\geq3(a+b+c)$$ or after squaring of the both sides
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{(4a^2+c^2+ab+2ac+bc)(4b^2+a^2+2ab+ac+bc)}\geq\sum_{cyc}(2a^2+7ab)$$ or after squaring of the both sides $$2\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{(4a^2+c^2+ab+2ac+bc)\prod_{cyc}(4a^2+c^2+ab+2ac+bc)}\geq$$
$$\geq\sum_{cyc}(14a^3b+17a^3c+31a^2b^2+100a^2bc).$$
But by AM-GM
$$2\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{(4a^2+c^2+ab+2ac+bc)\prod_{cyc}(4a^2+c^2+ab+2ac+bc)}\geq$$
$$\geq6\sqrt[3]{\prod_{cyc}(4a^2+c^2+ab+2ac+bc)^2}$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$216\prod_{cyc}(4a^2+c^2+ab+2ac+bc)^2\geq\left(\sum_{cyc}(14a^3b+17a^3c+31a^2b^2+100a^2bc)\right)^3,$$ which is true by BW:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=216%284x%5E2%2Bz%5E2%2B2xz%2Bxy%2Byz%29%5E2%284y%5E2%2Bx%5E2%2B2xy%2Bxz%2Byz%29%5E2%284z%5E2%2By%5E2%2B2yz%2Bxy%2Bxz%29%5E2-%2814%28x%5E3y%2By%5E3z%2Bz%5E3x%29%2B17%28x%5E3z%2By%5E3x%2Bz%5E3y%29%2B31%28x%5E2y%5E2%2Bx%5E2z%5E2%2By%5E2z%5E2%29%2B100xyz%28x%2By%2Bz%29%29%5E3%2Cx%3Da%2Cy%3Da%2Bu%2Cz%3Da%2Bv

Comment: (+1) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Some thoughts**.

The desired inequality is written as
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \sqrt{\frac{a + b + b^2}{3}} \ge 3. \tag{1}$$

We use the isolated fudging.

We can prove that, for all $a, b \ge 0$ with $a + b \le 3$,
$$\sqrt{\frac{a + b + b^2}{3}} \ge \frac{6a^{3} + 9{a}^{2}b + 9a{b}^{2} + 3{b}^{3} - 37{a}^{2} - 58ab - 19{
  b}^{2} + 117a + 150b
}{180}. \tag{2}$$
(This inequality is true which is verified by *Mathematica*.)

Using (2), we have
\begin{align*}
 &\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \sqrt{\frac{a + b + b^2}{3}}\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{6a^{3} + 9{a}^{2}b + 9a{b}^{2} + 3{b}^{3} - 37{a}^{2} - 58ab - 19{
   b}^{2} + 117a + 150b
 }{180}\\[6pt]
    ={}& 3 + \frac{1}{180}(a + b + c - 3)(9a^2 + 9b^2 + 9c^2 - 29a - 29b - 29c + 180)\\[6pt]
    ={}& 3.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

*My second proof*.

The desired inequality is written as
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \sqrt{\frac{a + b + b^2}{3}} \ge 3. \tag{1}$$

We have $\frac{(a + b) + b^2}{3} \le \frac{3 + 3^2}{3} = 4$,
$\frac{(b + c) + c^2}{3} \le \frac{3 + 3^2}{3} = 4$, and $\frac{(c + a) + a^2}{3} \le \frac{3 + 3^2}{3} = 4$.

We use the following bound: for all $x\in [0, 4]$,
$$\sqrt x \ge \frac14 x + \frac98 - \frac{9}{16x + 8}. \tag{2}$$
(*Note*: $\mathrm{LHS}^2 - \mathrm{RHS}^2
= \frac{x(4 - x)(x - 1)^2}{4(2x + 1)^2}\ge 0$.)

Using (2), it suffices to prove that
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \left(\frac14\cdot \frac{a + b + b^2}{3}  + \frac98 - \frac{9}{16\cdot \frac{a + b + b^2}{3} + 8}\right) \ge 3. \tag{3}$$

After homogenization, letting $Q = (a + b + c)/3$, it suffices to prove that
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \left(\frac14\cdot \frac{aQ + bQ + b^2}{3Q^2}  + \frac98 - \frac{9}{16\cdot \frac{aQ + bQ + b^2}{3Q^2} + 8}\right) \ge 3 $$
or (after clearing the denominators)
\begin{align*}
 &15\,{a}^{7}b+9\,{a}^{7}c+45\,{a}^{6}{b}^{2}-40\,{a}^{6}bc+156\,{a}^{6}
 {c}^{2}+156\,{a}^{5}{b}^{3}-215\,{a}^{5}{b}^{2}c\\
 &+46\,{a}^{5}b{c}^{2}+
 288\,{a}^{5}{c}^{3}+267\,{a}^{4}{b}^{4}-247\,{a}^{4}{b}^{3}c-104\,{a}^
 {4}{b}^{2}{c}^{2}-88\,{a}^{4}b{c}^{3}\\
 &+267\,{a}^{4}{c}^{4}+288\,{a}^{3}
 {b}^{5}-88\,{a}^{3}{b}^{4}c-288\,{a}^{3}{b}^{3}{c}^{2}-288\,{a}^{3}{b}
 ^{2}{c}^{3}-247\,{a}^{3}b{c}^{4}\\
 &+156\,{a}^{3}{c}^{5}+156\,{a}^{2}{b}^{
  6}+46\,{a}^{2}{b}^{5}c-104\,{a}^{2}{b}^{4}{c}^{2}-288\,{a}^{2}{b}^{3}{
  c}^{3}-104\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}{c}^{4}\\
 &-215\,{a}^{2}b{c}^{5}+45\,{a}^{2}{c}^
 {6}+9\,a{b}^{7}-40\,a{b}^{6}c-215\,a{b}^{5}{c}^{2}-247\,a{b}^{4}{c}^{3
 }-88\,a{b}^{3}{c}^{4}\\
&+46\,a{b}^{2}{c}^{5}-40\,ab{c}^{6}+15\,a{c}^{7}+
 15\,{b}^{7}c+45\,{b}^{6}{c}^{2}+156\,{b}^{5}{c}^{3}+267\,{b}^{4}{c}^{4
 }\\
&+288\,{b}^{3}{c}^{5}+156\,{b}^{2}{c}^{6}+9\,b{c}^{7}\\
&\ge 0.\tag{4}
\end{align*}

The Buffalo Way (BW) kills it.
In detail, WLOG, assume that $c = \min(a, b, c)$ and let $b = c + s, a = c + t$ for $s, t \ge 0$. (4) is written as
\begin{align*}
  &\left( 4374\,{s}^{2}-4374\,st+4374\,{t}^{2} \right) {c}^{6}\\
  &+ \left( 
 6723\,{s}^{3}+6318\,{s}^{2}t-243\,s{t}^{2}+6723\,{t}^{3} \right) {c}^{
  5}\\
 &+ \left( 4725\,{s}^{4}+12825\,{s}^{3}t+12555\,{s}^{2}{t}^{2}+1890\,s
 {t}^{3}+4725\,{t}^{4} \right) {c}^{4}\\
 &+ \left( 1745\,{s}^{5}+8449\,{s}^
 {4}t+16082\,{s}^{3}{t}^{2}+7658\,{s}^{2}{t}^{3}+1726\,s{t}^{4}+1745\,{
  t}^{5} \right) {c}^{3}\\
 &+ \left( 329\,{s}^{6}+2562\,{s}^{5}t+8124\,{s}^{
  4}{t}^{2}+7084\,{s}^{3}{t}^{3}+2697\,{s}^{2}{t}^{4}+699\,s{t}^{5}+329
 \,{t}^{6} \right) {c}^{2}\\
 &+ ( 24s^{7}+335s^{6}t+1846s^
 {5}t^{2}+2420s^{4}{t}^{3}+1601s^{3}{t}^{4}+523s^{2}{t}^{
  5}+155st^{6}+24t^{7} ) c\\
 &+9\,{s}^{7}t+156\,{s}^{6}{t}^{2}
 +288\,{s}^{5}{t}^{3}+267\,{s}^{4}{t}^{4}+156\,{s}^{3}{t}^{5}+45\,{s}^{
  2}{t}^{6}+15\,s{t}^{7}\\
 &\ge 0. \tag{5}
\end{align*}
It is very easy to prove that all the coefficients of $c^6, c^5, c^4, c^3, c^2, c, c^0$ are non-negative.

We are done.